# Strange error with svmono and quotation

Tags: errors, sv-classes

When I try to use `svmono`, it runs into a handful of these errors:

```
Error   Missing number, treated as zero.
```

The help provided for this:

```
This is usually caused by a LaTeX command expecting but not finding
either a number or a length as an argument. You may have omitted an
argument, or a square bracket in the text may have been mistaken for
the beginning of an optional argument. This error is also caused by
putting \protect in front of either a length command or a command such
as \value that produces a number.
```

And

```
Error   Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

And the help for this:

```
If you just got a

      ! Missing number, treated as zero.

error, then this is part of the same problem.  If not, it means that
LaTeX was expecting a length as an argument and found a number
instead.  The most common cause of this error is writing 0 instead of
something like 0in for a length of zero, in which case typing return
should result in correct output. However, the error can also be caused
by omitting a command argument.
```

The location of the errors is in the beginning of the body some `quotation` environments.

---

Here's a minimal working example that throws these errors:

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  Plus grande est
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

The error is thrown between the "g" and "r":

```
--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   g
l.6   Plus g
            rande est
```

Basically, all the quotation environments whose bodies begin with "plus" or "Plus" throw this error.

I can get around the error by writing "{plus}" or "{Plus}" instead, but why would I have to do this?

Comment: "Running into font issues" isn't exactly a specific diagnosis. Please post an MWE and state *which* font issues you encounter.

Comment: if it's this one http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/vision/F4K_BOOK/SPRINGER/styles/svmono.cls I couldn't see anything (although I didn't try) but if you are using the class to submit to springer and they are using a pdftex workflow xetex support isn't really an issue.

Comment: @Mico I've added more detail. It actually isn't a font error but some issue with units and the `quotation` environment.

Comment: That does not help anything. Please provide a minimal example as others gave already requested. Then they can copy it and test it (without having to add anything) and see if it works on their systems. Right now we are drawing blanks as we do not know any details about your doc other than you are using svmono and have an issue with quotation

Comment: @daleif I can't reproduce it with a minimal working example, nor does LaTeX give any other errors and warnings that what I quoted above.

Comment: Then do the following: copy the problematic file to a new file name. Then start reducing it by out commenting or deleting stuff until you come down to something that can be used as an mwe you can give us. This is basically the procedure the rest of us use when we encounter strange unexplainable errors. Sometimes it is the only way. Also why do you think it's us quotation that gives you the error? Have you looked in the actual log file? Sometimes editors don't parse the errors that well so the error might be something completely different, perhaps listed earlier in the log.

Comment: @daleif Actually, I got a minimal working example now. See my edited question.

Comment: That is really really strange. I'm not at a pc so cannot test. Is there by any chance an unprintable char between g and r?

Comment: @daleif Nope, I checked that.

Comment: I then you probably have to check the svmono manual. Quotation in that class might need extra option (compared to the standard version). Since you are not giving any strange thing might happen because it is using the text as arguments and they are not in an expected form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the way `svmono` implements the `quotation` environment.

The definition is

```
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\par\addvspace{6pt}
                \list{}{\listparindent12\p@%
                        \leftmargin=12\p@%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@%
                        \small}%
                \item\relax\hskip-\listparindent}
               {\endlist}
```

When the quotation starts with the words "plus" or "minus" these words are interpreted as basic TeX commands for adding or subtracting lengths.  Thus one has either to terminate the computation or enclosing the computation in a group.

Thus replacing the line

```
\item\relax\hskip-\listparindent
```

with

```
\item\relax\hskip-\listparindent\relax
```

prevents the words "plus" and "minus" to be understood as operators.

Comment: Nice deduction, hadn't seen that one coming.

Comment: Better yet, `\item\relax\hspace{-\listparindent}`